# MTW Box 10.1 E Additivity for covariant differentiation: Is this really a comprehensive proof?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields, lie-algebra

This question is a prelude to another question I intend to ask.

The following is from MTW *Box 10.1 E. Additivity for covariant differentiation*:

[image]

> E. In the real physical world, be it Newtonian or relativistic, parallel transport of a triangle cannot break its legs apart: (1) $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B},\mathbf{C}$ initially such that $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{C};$ (2) $\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B},\mathbf{C}$ each parallel transported with himself by freely falling (inertial) observer; (3) then $\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{C}$ always. Any other result would violate the equivalence principle!
>
> 1. Consequence of this (as seen by following through definition of covariant derivative, and by noting that any vector $\mathbf{u}$ can be regarded as the tangent vector to a freely falling world line):
>    $$\mathbf{\nabla}_{\mathbf{u}}\left(\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{w}\right)=\mathbf{\nabla}_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{\nabla}_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{w}$$
>    for any vector $\mathbf{u}$ and vector fields $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}.$
> 2. Consequence of this, combined with symmetry of covariant derivative, and with additivity of the "closer of quadrilaterals" $\left[\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\right]:$
>    $$\mathbf{\nabla}_{\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{n}}\mathbf{v}=\mathbf{\nabla}_{\mathbf{u}}\mathbf{v}+\mathbf{\nabla}_{\mathbf{n}}\mathbf{v}.$$

The statement "*noting that any vector $\mathbf{u}$ can be regarded as the tangent vector to a freely falling world line*", seems problematic.  Can't $\mathbf{u}$ be spacelike?  In particular, in part E.2. we find $\mathbf{n}$ is used.  In other places, Chapter 11, for example, $\mathbf{n}$ is called the geodesic separation; which is pretty clearly spacelike.

**Is their "proof" incomplete, and the statement I described as problematic, in fact incorrect?**

Comment: I think here they are dealing with a parallel transport along a timelike geodesic only. And it is meant as a motivation.  After the box (which by the way is 10.2 in my copy), they say "any rule $\nabla$, that....is called by differential geometers a symmetric covariant derivative".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are technically right. I think what they mean here is that any vector can be regarded as a tangent vector to a geodesic. Your point is that freeling bodies are only associated with time-like geodesics.